# How to display Access data in a DataTable in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I'm new to C#. I'm having a difficult time displaying my Access data in a DataTable. Here is the code:

```
        try
        {
            reader.Read();
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                if (selectedCourse == reader["CourseName"].ToString())
                {
                    match = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    match = false;
                }
            }
            if (match == true)
            {

                tabControl.SelectedTab = tabPage1; // opens results page
                string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\...454_Database.accdb";

                DataTable results = new DataTable();

                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
                {
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select c.PeriodID, c.CourseName, c.Teacher, t.Room" 
                              + "FROM Courses c JOIN Teacher t ON t.TeacherID = c.TeacherID"
                              + "WHERE [CourseName] ='" + cboxClass.Text + "'", conn);

                    conn.Open();

                    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

                    adapter.Fill(results);
                    dataTblResults.DataSource = results;
```

I can tell the data is being compared to the db and it correctly determines if the query has results or not. However, when there are results, they do not get displayed on the data table. Is it because it doesn't know which columns correspond to the columns in the data table?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a DataGridView?  You may have improperly changed some parameters in the DataGridView.  I would delete the DataGridView and add new DGV to form which will use default settting.

Answer (score 0):

How is your datagrid configured?

Try setting: (before setting the DataSource)

```
dataTblResults.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataTblResults.DockStyle.Fill = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Dataset first. Then turn it to a datatable

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.fill(ds)

if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count >= 1)
                    {
                        results = ds.Tables[0];
                    }

dataTblResults.DataSource = results;
```

I dont think this is what you are looking for but maybe it'll bring you closer to the answer